# Не устанавливается gulp на систему

Tags: javascript, gulp, visual-studio-code, npm

Устанавливаю gulp как надо - скачалось и в итоге как я понял не в ту папку.. А как исправить незнаю, пытался исправить в итоге ещё хуже сделал
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: вы пробовали запустить установившийся гульп?

Comment: Я навводил каких-то команд в консоль, и теперь gulp устанаваливается в другую папку. И вообще глобально не устанавливается.

Comment: Конечно пробовал, я виндовс переустановил и блин начались проблемы с gulp-пом, а так код работает.

Comment: гульп, как команда, запускается в терминале?

Comment: нет не запускается

Comment: Пишет что команда не найдена